# row_number-like method which restarts at 0 for each group

Tags: postgresql

Say there is a table which stores a hierarchical structure like this:

```
item_id | hierarchical_id 
--------+-----------------
    1   | ;1;
    2   | ;1;2;
    3   | ;1;2;3;
    4   | ;1;2;4;
    5   | ;1;2;4;5;
```

The hierarchy stored here is 1 as root, 2 is a child of 1, 3 and 4 are children of 2 and 5 is the child of 4.

The query

```
SELECT
  -- the substr is used to remove the first and last semicolumns
  regexp_split_to_table(substr(hierarchical_id, 2, length(hierarchical_id) - 2)
                        , E';'
  ) as parent_id,
  item_id,
  hierarchical_id
FROM 
  table
```

returns

```
parent_id | item_id | hierarchical_id
----------+---------+-----------------
       1  |    1    | ;1;
       1  |    2    | ;1;2;
       2  |    2    | ;1;2;
       1  |    3    | ;1;2;3;
       3  |    3    | ;1;2;3;
       1  |    4    | ;1;2;3;
       2  |    4    | ;1;2;4;
       4  |    4    | ;1;2;4;
       1  |    5    | ;1;2;4;5;
       2  |    5    | ;1;2;4;5;
       4  |    5    | ;1;2;4;5;
       5  |    5    | ;1;2;4;5;
```

How can I modify the query to get a 4th column like this:

```
parent_id | item_id | hierarchical_id | distance
----------+---------+-----------------+---------
       1  |    1    | ;1;             | 0
       1  |    2    | ;1;2;           | 1
       2  |    2    | ;1;2;           | 0
       1  |    3    | ;1;2;3;         | 2 
       2  |    3    | ;1;2;3;         | 1
       3  |    3    | ;1;2;3;         | 0
       1  |    4    | ;1;2;4;         | 2
       2  |    4    | ;1;2;4;         | 1
       4  |    4    | ;1;2;4;         | 0
       1  |    5    | ;1;2;4;5;       | 3
       2  |    5    | ;1;2;4;5;       | 2
       4  |    5    | ;1;2;4;5;       | 1
       5  |    5    | ;1;2;4;5;       | 0
```

The meaning of `distance` is the distance between the `item_id` and the `parent_id` on the current row. Eg: the distance between a node and itself is 0, and the distance between a node and its parent is 1, the distance between a node and its parent parent is 2 etc. It does not have to start at 0.

`row_number` would work fine if I could get it to restart at 0 for each group of equal `item_id`s, since the ids in `hierarchical_id` are ordered.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match the output of the query you provided for the sample input data. There are three rows with `item_id` = 3 in the query's output, not two.

Comment: It's also not exactly clear what exactly those `distance`s are supposed to *mean* or how they're derived. I've taken a stab at it in the answer, but the question is not super clear. OTOH, at least you provided sample data, even if I did have to hand-convert it to INSERTs.

Comment: I updated the expected output, you are right, there was a row missing. As for the distance, I tried to explain it a little after the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window functions give you lots of control; see [4.2.8. Window Function Calls](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS).

The key thing you need is:

```
row_number() OVER (PARTITON BY item_id ORDER BY hierarchical_id)
```

Given data:

```
create table t ( item_id integer, hierarchical_id text );
insert into t (item_id, hierarchical_id) values
(1,';1;'),
(2,';1;2;'),
(3,';1;2;3;'),
(4,';1;2;4;'),
(5,';1;2;4;5;');
```

the query:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT regexp_split_to_table(substr(hierarchical_id, 2, length(hierarchical_id) - 2), E';') as parent_id,
    item_id,
    hierarchical_id
  FROM t
)
SELECT 
  *,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY parent_id DESC) - 1 AS distance
FROM x
ORDER BY item_id, parent_id;
```

produces:

```
 parent_id | item_id | hierarchical_id | distance 
-----------+---------+-----------------+----------
 1         |       1 | ;1;             |        0
 1         |       2 | ;1;2;           |        1
 2         |       2 | ;1;2;           |        0
 1         |       3 | ;1;2;3;         |        2
 2         |       3 | ;1;2;3;         |        1
 3         |       3 | ;1;2;3;         |        0
 1         |       4 | ;1;2;4;         |        2
 2         |       4 | ;1;2;4;         |        1
 4         |       4 | ;1;2;4;         |        0
 1         |       5 | ;1;2;4;5;       |        3
 2         |       5 | ;1;2;4;5;       |        2
 4         |       5 | ;1;2;4;5;       |        1
 5         |       5 | ;1;2;4;5;       |        0
```

which looks roughly right, but since your expected output doesn't seem to match the output of the query you provided when I run it (Pg 9.1) it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: I tried that (suggestion before your edit), but I get syntax error at or near "GROUP"
LINE 38: row_number() OVER (GROUP BY item_id) AS i

Comment: I just tried the current suggestion, with PARTITION BY item_id and I get 1 for all rows.

Comment: I was editing to say that it works if I move the row_count in another select, which is exactly what you added in the update. If it does not match the sample data, then the mistake is in the sample. Thank you!

Comment: @Sorin No worries. Note that this only works so long as `hierarchical_id` is strictly in descending order; if you had a `hierarchical_id` of `;5;2;1;3;` then it'd fall over completely.

Comment: @Sorin Now you've explained the how and why not just the what, better answer posted. Speaking of "why" - why store the hierarchical_id in such a contorted format, not an array of integers?

Comment: I am not the owner of the database - I just do some processing. By looking at what is available to me, I can't tell of any good reason why it's stored like this.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the question is better refined here's a formulation that better expresses the intention, not just the results:

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;

SELECT 
  exploded.*, 
  array_length(h_arr,1) - idx(h_arr,parent_id) AS distance
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(h_arr) AS parent_id, item_id, h_arr 
  FROM (
    SELECT
      item_id,
      regexp_split_to_array( trim(hierarchical_id,';'),';')::int[] as h_arr
    FROM t
  ) h_as_intarray
) exploded;
```

... though it's a bit slower due to all the passes required. If the `hierarchical_id` were stored as an integer array in the first place like it probably should be:

```
ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN hierarchical_id TYPE int[] 
USING (regexp_split_to_array( trim(hierarchical_id,';'),';')::int[]);
```

you'd have a much nicer query because you'd be rid of all that horrid regexp string processing:

```
SELECT 
  exploded.*,
  array_length(hierarchical_id,1) - idx(hierarchical_id,parent_id)  AS distance
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(hierarchical_id) AS parent_id, item_id, hierarchical_id 
  FROM t
) exploded;
```

... which for bonus points is also 3x faster on this tiny dataset, and is likely to maintain or extend that lead on bigger datasets.

Comment: This is a nice alternative, and I'll keep it in mind in case I'll have to design something similar.